# Confusing notation: Presentation theory of symmetric groups (Coxeter presentations)

Tags: finite-groups, symmetric-groups, quantifiers, group-presentation, coxeter-groups

I am having trouble to understand the notations used in [Coxeter presentations of symmetric groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Presentation_theory_of_symmetric_groups). The notation is defined as follows.

Suppose $G$ is the symmetric group on the set $\left\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n+1\right\}$ . Then, $G$ is isomorphic to a Coxeter group, with the following Coxeter presentation:

$$
G \cong \langle s_i | s^2_i = 1\forall1 \le i \le n, \left(s_i s_{i+1}\right)^3 = 1\forall1 \le i \le n - 1, \left(s_i s_j\right)^2 = 1\forall1 \le i < j \le n, |i - j| > 1 \rangle
$$.

I am not sure how to read this expression, especially, $1\forall1$. It doesn't look like $\forall$ is the universal quantifier here.

Comment: The notation is a bit strange: I'd rewrite this perhaps as $G \cong \langle s_i \vert s_i^2 = 1 \, \forall i : 1 \leq i \leq n ; \cdots \rangle$.

Comment: @Travis, did you mean $G \cong \langle s_i \vert s_i^2 = 1, \forall i : 1 \leq i \leq n ; \cdots \rangle$?

Comment: @Travis, you are probably missing a comma.

Comment: think of it as $s_i^2 = 1$ for all $i \in [1..n]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably:

$$
G \cong \langle \ s_i \mid \forall i \ (1 \le i \le n \to s^2_i = 1) \text { and }$$

$$\forall i \ (1 \le i \le (n - 1) \to (s_i s_{i+1})^3 = 1) \text { and }$$

$$\forall i \ \forall j \ ((1 \le i < j \le n \text { and } |i - j| > 1) \to (s_i s_j)^2 = 1) \ \rangle$$